# How do I block the use of @everyone and @here? with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord

I want to make my bot block @everyone and @here and send a "u need admin role to do that" message
but still allow certain roles to use @everyone and @here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bot can only catch messages after they send - this means everyone would still get an annoying ping from the person using @everyone, then the message would go away. Only a half measure.

Restricting @everyone/@here to certain roles is [possible in normal Discord](https://discordhelp.net/disable-everyone) (since this tutorial was created, the role permission was changed to "Mention @everyone, @here and All Roles").
When you've done this and someone types @everyone, it will be treated like any other message. Here's an an image of my testing: Notice only one of the messages has the gold highlight: that was the time the account had the permission to send @everyone messages.

[image: different @everyones]